# Pimcore 5: Programmatically Adding a Brick to an Areablock (Document Automation)

Tags: automation, document, pimcore-v5

I'm attempting to migrate rather intricate pages in a [Pimcore 4](https://pimcore.com/en/resources/legacy) instance to an updated [Pimcore](https://pimcore.com/en/products/platform) instance (5 at the time of this post).

I've managed to translate the [objects](https://pimcore.com/docs/5.x/Development_Documentation/Objects/index.html) and [asset](https://pimcore.com/docs/5.x/Development_Documentation/Assets/index.html) assignments to those object's [fields](https://pimcore.com/docs/5.x/Development_Documentation/Objects/Object_Classes/Data_Types/index.html) already, however I've not been able to find a way to automate the inclusion and configuration of [bricks](https://pimcore.com/docs/5.x/Development_Documentation/Documents/Editables/Areablock/Bricks.html) into the [Areablock](https://pimcore.com/docs/5.x/Development_Documentation/Documents/Editables/Areablock/index.html) editable content type in a [document](https://pimcore.com/docs/5.x/Development_Documentation/Documents/index.html).

As per the Pimcore 5 docs, document creation is done via:

```
<?php

  // Create a new document, name it, and assign a parent...
  $page = new \Pimcore\Model\Document\Page();
  $page->setKey( 'my-new-document' );
  $page->setParentId( 82 );

  // This is where you'd automate the brick configuration...

  // All done, save the document...
  $page->save();
```

If anyone has had any successful experience with this I would very much appreciate any assistance provided.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the output of getElements(), modifying as needed, and feed it into setElements()

```
    $page = \Pimcore\Model\Document::getById($page_of_interest);
    $elements = $page->getElements();
    // Update $elements (namely changing documentId to the id of the new page, and updating field names/types)
    $new_page = new \Pimcore\Model\Document\Page();
    $new_page->setKey('my-new-page');
    $new_page->setElements($elements);
    $new_page->save();
```